# Ajax contact form issue with string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, contact-form

i've been trying to set up a simple contact form with PHP but it isn't working, i used [this](https://spruce.it/noise/simple-ajax-contact-form/) tutorial and it worked at the first try but when i tried to customize it and add a few fields it failed miserably. I think is something between Ajax and PHP when i send the data but i honestly don't know.

This is the code i'm using:

```
HTML

<form id="formulariocontacto">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Phone">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="text" id="direccion" name="direccion" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Adress">
            <textarea rows="14" id="comentario" name="comentario" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="botonform" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">SEND</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>  

jQuery

 $("#formulariocontacto").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var nombre = $("#name").val();
  var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var direccion = $("#direccion").val();
  var comentario = $("#comentario").val();
  var dataString = 'nombre=' + nombre + '&email=' + email + '&comentario=' + comentario + '&telefono' + telefono + '&direccion' + direccion;
  function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
  };

  if (isValidEmail(email) && (comentario.length > 100) && (nombre.length > 1)){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "procesar.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
      $('.exito').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    });
  } else{
    $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
  }

  return false;
});

PHP

<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['comentario'])  ) {
$name_field=$_POST['nombre'];
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$telefono_field=$_POST['telefono'];
$direccion_field=$_POST['direccion'];
$mensaje_field=$_POST['comentario'];
$subject=.$_POST['nombre']" V&#237;a mysite.com";
$mensaje="Nombre: $name_field\n Email: $email_field\n Tel&#233;fono: $telefono_field\n Direcci&#243;n: $direccion_field\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje_field";
  // detect & prevent header injections
$test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
  exit;
}
}  
 //send email
 mail( "mymail@mysite.com", $subject, $mensaje, "From: " . $email );
}
?>
```

Im trying to make a more complete message by adding some extra fields you can see the var "$mensaje" in the PHP

Comment: Even if you get what you want working, I would just like to make you aware that your mail() input is not sanitized therefore giving spammers an ability to hijack your form and send masses of spam.

Comment: yes i know, any comments on how to approach this problem?

Comment: validate anything that goes into the headers (in this example, your from email). sanitize your subject. sanitize all fields that a user can input on. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228389-preventing-php-mail-header-injections/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what error you're getting or what's not working, I can only presume you're not receiving all of the data that's being submitted?

If so, it is because you're not passing it in the dataString.

```
 var nombre = $("#name").val();
 var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
 var email = $("#email").val();
 var direccion = $("#direccion").val();
 var comentario = $("#comentario").val();
 var dataString = 'nombre=' + nombre + '&email=' + email + '&comentario=' + comentario + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&direccion=' + direccion;
```

To sanitise the email input:

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

Then your mail function can be:

```
mail("mymail@mail.com",$subject,$mensaje,"From:" . $email);
```

## Update

Your ajax call should be:

```
if (isValidEmail(email) && (comentario.length > 100) && (nombre.length > 1)){
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "procesar.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            $('.exito').fadeIn(1000);
        },
        error: function(){
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
}
```

## Update 2

```
  $subject=.$_POST['nombre']" V&#237;a mysite.com";
```

should be

```
  $subject=$_POST['nombre']." V&#237;a mysite.com";
```

That is what's producing the 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i updated the dataString line and added the sanitized email input, however im still getting my ajax error popped up

Comment: the one i stated in the jquery if the "success: function()" doesnt work.. is not a jquery console error is just my "else"

Comment: im getting a syntax error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

Comment: I've replicated it this end and I'm not receiving any errors. Do you have a link to a live example?

Comment: veromonaco.com/contact

Comment: im recieving a 500 error (internal server error) when i try to call the php file

Comment: `$subject=.$_POST['nombre']" V&#237;a mysite.com";` should be `$subject= $_POST['nombre'] . " V&#237;a mysite.com";`

Comment: it's working!!!! im getting the mail delivered, however neither my "#exito" message  or the "#error" message appears

Comment: Where are your .exito & .error divs? I can't see them in the source code.

Comment: they are inside the form with a display:none property

Comment: I can't see them in the source code of veromonaco.com/contact, which means they're not there.

Comment: my dear friend, everything is working now, you are my savior and i love you

Comment: however, i have one last little issue, my mail gets delivered to the spam folder in gmail ..

Comment: If this is for a contact form that's only being delivered to yourself, I would opt to use a static email rather than the clients.  `mail("mymail@mail.com",$subject,$mensaje,"From: Website <website@example.org>");`

Answer (score 0):

you have forgot equal.

**CHANGE THIS**

```
var dataString = 'nombre=' + nombre + '&email=' + email + '&comentario=' + comentario + '&telefono' + telefono + '&direccion' + direccion;
```

**TO**

```
 var dataString = 'nombre=' + nombre + '&email=' + email + '&comentario=' + comentario + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&direccion=' + direccion;
```